# соотношение сторон libvlc

Tags: android, видео, vlc, online-video

Использую библиотеку  [libvlc](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk) версии 1.0.6, не могу разобраться, как получить соотношение сторон , воспроизводимого видео.
 Пытался использовать данный метод

```
@Override
public void setSurfaceLayout(int width, int height, int visible_width, int visible_width, int visible_height, int sar_num, int sar_den)
}
```

По идее `sar_num` и `sar_den` это и есть данные о соотношении, но они при воспроизведении видео, соотношении которого примерно 16:9 (на глаз), выдает `sar_num=16`, `sar_den=15` при первом видео и `sar_num=1`, `sar_den=1` при воспроизведении второго